# MHYDRO Hydrodynamics (MIKE HYDRO)

Tags: hydrology, models

I have run a MIKE HYDRO 1D simulation to completion without any errors being flagged. How do I check for any instability within the model or whether the simulated results are realistic?

Answer (score 2):

Checking the hydraulics of your 1D MHYDRO setup is usually a good starting point. This can be done by opening the 1D result file in Mike View. Click on the “select profile” icon and then click a start and end point of the river segment that you are interested in. Thereafter select “yes” to close the profile selection so that the profile can be drawn. The data type to be selected is “water level”. Once the profile has been drawn, you should notice that the profile gradually decreases in water level from left to right. This is the type of trend you’re looking for.